# Remove Objects With Same Element From A List Java

Tags: java

`Topic` is an object made up of:

```
String Name
Int Id
```

e.g.

```
topic1:
Name: Topic1
Id: 1

topic2:
Name: Topic1
Id: 2
```

I have a list of `{topic1, topic2}`

I want a list of topics with unique names. So my ideal output would be a list containing just `{topic1}`.

`.distinct()` doesn't work because the Ids are different, so the objects are different.

How do I get this in Java?

Comment: If two objects have the same name, which object do you want to keep? What if your list is `[topic2, topic1]`?

Comment: Fundamentally, the system can't "just know" what operation you want to preform on a list like this, so it only provides primitives and you have to be able to supply the rest.  Take a look at [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and the way they are used to parameterize various list operators.

Comment: That said, I'd agree that not having some sort of "removeAll( predicate )" for a list might be a bit of an oversight.

Comment: @markspace You mean `removeIf()`?

Comment: I said "for a list" and meant the `List` interface, so no not really.  I suppose I should have been more clear.  But "removeIf" on List would be a lot handier than having it only ArrayList (which is what I assume you mean).

Comment: @markspace It's on `Collection`.

Comment: OK I stand corrected then.

Comment: FYI: [`Collection#removeIf( Predicate )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) in Java 8+.